# Plotting my timesheet

Tags: org-agenda, org-clock-table

I am using doom emacs.
I try to clock every hour i spent and it is working quite good.
After one week i have something like this:

```
| test | test2 |
|------+-------|
| 1:30 |    10 |
| 1:45 |    12 |
| 1d   |    14 |
```

It is a bit different, but the first obstacle, i face is that the plot is not working correctly with "1d" and 1:45 for example:

If i call gnuplot to do the table, it is outputting:

[image]

How can a force gnuplot to plot the time correctly?

Comment: I think you will have to convert all the values to common units. How is the table generated in the first place? Here you show the two columns plotted as independent graphs, so you are using the row number in the table as the x-coordinate and the two values in each row as y-coordinates for the two graphs. Is that correct? Or  should the first column be the x-coordinate and the second column the y-coordinate?

Comment: @NickD it is actually only an example created by me. So i should turn 1d into hours, correct?
With the second column i only wanted to show, that numbers like 1:45 do not plot correctly here. Is there not a way to plot hours?

Comment: Maybe - I'm no gnuplot expert, but see the [Time/Date data](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node76.html) section in the manual.